# Django how to use modelform to show the error messages

Tags: python, django

I use django modelform to save data,
I use ajax ,so it won't redirect to other page.
when submit,the view `create_post` will deal with it.

But I have a question,if I type 'abc' in the email's filed and submit.
I know it won't pass the validation,But it doesn't print the error message to let the user know where is the mistake.
How can I edit to reach it? 
Please guide me.  Thank you .

[EDIT]
when I edit to this `return render(request, "zh_tw/maininfo.html#5thpage",{form: 'form'})` 
Now if I type 'abc' in email field,the post is 200 ok.
But when it render back to this page, it will alert 'ERROR!'
it seems like it run this part in ajax:
             `error: function(ts){
                alert('ERROR!!!');
                window.location.reload();
            },`

template/main.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' },
    });

    // Submit post on submit
    $('#create_post').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var message = $("#message").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '{% url 'core:create_post' %}',
            data: { "name":name,"email":email,"message":message,},
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            error: function(ts){
                alert('ERROR!!!');
                window.location.reload();
            },
            success: function(dataArr){
                if(dataArr == 2){
                    alert('success!');
                    window.location.reload();
                }else{
                    alert('something wrong!');
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

<div class="section" id="contact">
    <div class="message">
        <form action="." method="POST" id="create_post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        {{ form }}
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="name" placeholder="your name">
            <input type="text" name="Email" id="email" placeholder="your email">
        </div>
        <textarea placeholder="talk?" name = "Message" id="message"></textarea>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

views.py

```
def maininfo(request):
    # return render(request, 'english/maininfo.html',)
    return render(request, 'zh_tw/maininfo.html',)


def create_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MessageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.ip = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
            obj.save()
            return HttpResponse(2)
        return render(request, "zh_tw/maininfo.html#5thpage",{form: 'form'})
```

Comment: You haven't shown the whole of your view. Obviously if the form is not valid, ie there are errors, you need to return them so that the ajax can display them. What happens after the else statement?

Answer (score 0):

This will render form errors and form non-field errors in case you have them.

```
<div class="section" id="contact">
    <div class="message">
        <form action="." method="POST" id="create_post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        {{ form }}
        <button type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a bit improved view:

```
def create_post(request):
    form = MessageForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.ip = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
        obj.save()
    return render_to_response(request, template="your_template.html", context={form: 'form'})
```

Comment: the post is 200 OK ,but it alert the ````error: function(ts){
                alert('操作失敗');
                window.location.reload();
            },````  part